# Previous View Controller is seen under the next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a second view controller which segues from the previous one. How can I adjust the opacity of my SecondViewController so that I may still see the previous view controller under it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To present a view modally and still be able to see the presenting view controller under it. Present your SecondViewController in code like this:

```
 let vc = secondViewController
 secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Using this, ensure your secondViewController primary view has an alpha value less than 1.0 so you will be able to see through it. Also, the animated parameter can be true or false, it shouldn't affect the result.
Using the `modalPresentationStyle` accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: so this will be presented modally? i want to to use push view controller. is that possible?

Comment: @DanSaps Yes. In order to push, you would need to use a navigation controller and you said you weren't using that in one of your comments. That said, I don't think using a navigation controller would give you the view on view effect you are looking for.

Comment: I now embeded my view controller in navigation controller. And it works but another question, do I need to change all my push view implementation to presentViewController?

Comment: As far as I know, to get the desired effect, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just unclick/click **Animates** option through Interface Builder based on your requirement,

[image]

Comment: i am not using navigation controller for the next view. just plain view controller